# How to construct Empty BitVec in z3

Tags: z3

Algorithm:

```
if BitVecA > 0 
    BitVecB = Concat(BitVecA, BitVecB)
```

I want to Concat two conditional bitvec and with no else condition by using If

I want to using
BitVecB = Contact(BitVecA, If(BitVecA>0, BitVecA, EmptyBitVec )),
but len of BitVec cannot be zero

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what your question is. But if you look at https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FixedSizeBitVectors.shtml you'll see that SMTLib only allows bit-vectors that have strictly positive lengths. (i.e., zero-length bitvectors are not part of the logic.)

So, if you need to reason with 0-length bit vectors, you'll have to write your code to handle it outside of the SMTLib fragment; i.e., in your wrapper code. But without knowing what your context is, hard to answer in any further detail.